# Follow-Up: LTSpice “Error:undefined symbol in:” problem

Tags: ltspice, error, function

Thanks to those who have provided helpful answers on the original post. I've tried @Ernesto 's suggestions, but I must not be implementing them correctly as I'm still receiving similar errors. Please let me know what I'm missing.
[Original Post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/556823/ltspice-errorundefined-symbol-in-problem/556868?noredirect=1#comment1451387_556868)

**New Schematic and Test circuit:**
[image: Screenshot of Schematic for Symbol and test circuit]

The errors I received are:

> Questionable use of curly braces in "v4 n004 0 {fnmod(v(pos))}"
> ....Error: undefined symbol in: "(if((v)>0,5,0))"
> Questionable use of curly braces in "v5 n006 0 v={fnmod(v(mom))}"
> ....Error: undefined symbol in: "(if((v)>0,5,0))"
> Questionable use of curly braces in "v6 n005 0 v={fnmod(v(mom))}"
> ....Error: undefined symbol in: "(if((v)>0,5,0))"
> Error on line 22 : v:x1:4 x1:n004 0«:0» fnmod(v(n004)))
> ....Unknown parameter "fnmod"
> Error on line 23 : v:x1:5 x1:n006 0«:0» v=(fnmod(v(x1:mom)))
> ....Unknown parameter "v"
> Error on line 24 : v:x1:6 x1:n005 0«:0» v=(fnmod(v(x1:mom)))
> ....Unknown parameter "v"
> x1:c1: Increased Cpar to 4.7e-011
> x1:v6: Missing value, assumed 0V @ DC
> x1:v5: Missing value, assumed 0V @ DC
> x1:v4: Missing value, assumed 0V @ DC
> ***Dots** are mine*
>
> So, I'm sure I messed up on something.
> I also tried to make a subcircuit from the netlist and tried a variety of changes but received similar errors for those as well.

**Subcircuit:**

> - C:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\LTspiceXVII\Schematics\RM-Relay-SPDT.asc
>   .subckt RM-Relay-SPDT POS NEG COM1 N1 N2 
>   .func fnMod(x) {if(x>0,5,0)}
>   V2 +V 0 15 
>   V3 -V 0 -15 
>   XU2 N006 N1 COM1 -V 0 +V ADG1201 
>   XU1 N003 N002 +V 0 Mom level2 Avol=1Meg GBW=10Meg Slew=10Meg ilimit=25m rail=0 Vos=0 phimargin=45 en=0 enk=0 in=0 ink=0 Rin=500Meg
>   R1 Mom N003 100k tol=5 pwr=.125 
>   R2 N002 N001 100k tol=5 pwr=.125 
>   R3 N003 N004 10k tol=5 pwr=.125 
>   V1 N001 0 3.3 
>   R4 POS 0 100Meg tol=5 pwr=.125 
>   XU3 N005 N2 COM1 -V 0 +V ADG1201 
>   R5 NEG 0 100Meg tol=5 pwr=.125 
>   V4 N004 0 { V=fnMod( V(POS) ) } 
>   V5 N006 0 {if(V(Mom)>0,5,0)} 
>   V6 N005 0 {if(V(Mom)>0,5,0)}
>   C1 N004 0 47µ V=100 Irms=240m Rser=0.363 Lser=5.76604n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="865080862008 WCAP-ASLI 12,5x14" type="Al electrolytic"
>   .inc c:\Users\rober\OneDrive\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\sub\ADG1201.sub
>   .lib ADG1201.sub 
>   .lib UniversalOpamps.sub 
>   .backanno 
>   .ends RM-Relay-SPDT
>   .end

You can see in the .subckt that the definition for V4 isn't the same as V5 or V6 - This just shows me trying different things to see if they work... but they didn't. I'm really missing something.

Once again I am **grateful** for all the help I am receiving.

RobMcN

Comment: In the help docs section "General Structure and Conventions", it describes how different components have different prefix which is used by SPICE program. It seems you are using independent voltage source when behavioral source should be used (so "B4" not "V4").

Comment: Thanks.  I have to turn down for the night so I'll try the solution tomorrow. By the way,  is that in both the subckt and on the schematic? Kindly,  RobMcN

Comment: @RobMcN Like I said on the previous question, you need to use the `bv` symbol instead of `voltage`.  Replace V4, V5, and V6 with `bv` symbols and replace the `F(...)` part of the default value with your desired expressions, such that it looks like `V=<expression>`.  You're still doing the IF statement wrong, by the way.  Also, if you believe the previous question was answered sufficiently by Ernesto, then please accept it as shown here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235